# How to fetch client side when the server can go two different routes?

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api

I am unsure of how to do this but I have a post request server side that goes to two different routes depending on the result of a query.

```
app.post('/check', function(req, res) {
    connection.query("select exists (select * from visit WHERE id = ?) as 'res' ",
    id, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if(result[0].res == 0) {
        console.log("Doesn't exist in db.")
        res.redirect(307, '/post'); //goes to /post but after post it doesn't go to db
      }
  else {
    //if data exists update
    console.log("Exists in db.")
    res.redirect(307, '/up');  //goes to up but doesn't go to up.html afterwards
  }
});
```

So the request works above. Below it does not change the page of the web browser.

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    //connects to mysql to update database
    res.redirect('/post.html'); //---when database updates the page doesn't change
});
```

It does not work here below either:

```
app.post('/up', async function(req, res) {
  console.log("/qrupdate: post timeOut");
  let now = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  data = req.body;
  let id = data.id.toString();
  connection.query("UPDATE visit SET timeOut = ? WHERE id=?", [now, id],
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    res.redirect('/up.html');  //doesn't change page
});
```

So why doesn't the webpage change even though it is redirected? 
Also, if I need to do a fetch client side, what is the fetch supposed to look like?
I do not know if it is going one route or another, so can I do it; if post request is this, update the page at the specified location, else update the page at this location? I do not know what's possible or what it's supposed to look like.

```
fetch(api_url + '/qrcheck', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: qrdata
})
   .then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
  //So here it prints the requests but I guess I wanted to do some kind of if statement
//like if post request was /post then window.location = post.html. Else window.location = up.html
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

Comment: You say "goes to `/post`" -- do you merely mean the JavaScript engine enters the `app.post('/post', ...)` handler, or that you really do observe on the client a redirect to `/post`? If the latter, what is rendered on `/post`? What do you see on the client?

Comment: Hi apsillers, thanks for replying! It redirects to post but then nothing happens.  XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3000/check
[HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect 27ms]

XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3000/post
[HTTP/1.1 302 Found 3ms]

XHRGEThttp://localhost:3000/db.html [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 6ms] So I guess I need to do a fetch on my client side. Which I have done for /check, but how do I do a fetch for /post or /up?

Comment: When I say goes to /post I mean the request is successful, the client side doesn't change at all but everything is posted in the db correctly, literally the only problem I'm having is just going to the html pages. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wait, it looks like the XHR *does* ultimately resolve to the `.html` right? An HTTP `3xx` redirect says "make this request actually resolve at..." It does not mean "change the user's top level browsing context to..." -- to do that you'll need to execute `window.location = ...` in client JavaScript

Comment: Hi apsillers, see I felt like when it didn't go through /check it was updating the browser! I originally didn't have a check but it was working, then when I added the check it didn't update the browser which is why I had the problem. It is teaching me stuff though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still don't know why it doesn't change the page if it posts to /check and then /up, it doesn't go to up.html but would if it didn't have to go through /check first (I'm assuming it's something to do with it redirecting twice, if anyone can give any more information on that it would be helpful just so people know), but you can have an if statement in your fetch by using `data`.

```
fetch(api_url + '/check', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: qrdata
})
.then((data) => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
    //I have added two if statements to check the location
    //then the client side is updated to that page
  if (data.url == url + '/up.html') {
    window.location.replace(url + '/up.html');
  }
  if (data.url == url + '/post.html') {
    window.location.replace(url + '/post.html');
  }
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```